# Failed to determine a suitable driver class, Can you give solution on this?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

found this error..can you give solution over this

Comment: just adding a `spring-data-jpa` dependency is not enough, you should also add a database dependency and specify the db properties in `application.yml`. For an example see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database)

Comment: Please don't put irrelevant tags on your questions.  What you are asking has nothing to do with `[javascript]`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.